# A range variable used as an argument

Tags: vba, excel, variables, range

I'm writing a VBA function that outputs a range object. After I initialize the range object, I have trouble trying to use said object further as an argument (or, property). Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
Set HelpRange = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(StartRow + Counter, StartCol)  'works fine
Worksheets("sheet1").HelpRange.something ...
```

I'm obviously aiming for *worksheets(a).range(b)*, how can I do this when *range(b)* is a variable? It's obviously not working my way.

Comment: `Worksheets("sheet1").HelpRange.something ...` should just be `HelpRange.something ...` - `HelpRange` is a Range object, not a property or method of a Worksheet object

Comment: All right, but if I'm stuck with a range object and need to use the range in a worksheet property?

Comment: Why do you need to use it as a property of a worksheet.  You already have the range object - just use it - e.g. `HelpRange.Interior.Color = vbRed` will then change the colour of the range.  You no longer need to tell it which `Worksheet` object it belongs to - that is known by `HelpRange`'s `.Parent` property.

Comment: The `Range.Worksheet` property returns the worksheet on which `Range` is located. It looks like you would rather invert the relationship.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are thinking about ranges as if they were not associated with a particular worksheet.  But, every range is associated with a worksheet. Even when you write Range("A1") it really means ActiveSheet.Range("A1").  So when you write Worksheets("sheet1").HelpRange it means Worksheets("sheet1").Worksheets("sheet1").HelpRange, which doesn't make sense.  See?

Comment: @TonyM Although your explanation may (hopefully) get the message across ( :-) ), it isn't **strictly** true - `HelpRange` is a `Range` object, whereas `Range("A1")` is a call to a piece of code embedded within a `Worksheet` object (with the string `"A1"` being passed as a parameter to that code) and that code is then returning a `Range` object.  Because it is nearly lunchtime, and I'm starting to get hungry, an analogy would be that `HelpRange` is a cake, and `Range("A1")` is a chef who follows the recipe (`"A1"` in this case) to make a cake.

Comment: @YowE3K point taken -- I learned something -- thanks.

Comment: @TonyM Hopefully the point you took was valid - I'm no expert so it may not be. But I am **fairly** confident that that is the way to think of `Objects` -v- `Methods`/`Properties`. (But I could also be wildly wrong - I grew up in the era when objects were just called "well designed, reusable code" :D)

Comment: a range object is used as a variable... so you only need the variable name and nothing before it.